# LINQ old data being returned

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I didn't get any where on Microsoft's forum.  What worked for one user didn't work for me so I must be doing something wrong.

I need the data returned to match what's in the database, but 6 seconds later it's coming back as the previous data that was just updated.  I'm creating the context within the method and I'm using StoreWins, but maybe I'm using it incorrectly.

Here's an example method.

```
    public bool MyExampleMethod(long id, long newId, long oldId)
    {
        using (var context = new myEntity())
        {
            my_table data = (from d in context.my_table
                             where d.id == id
                             select d).FirstOrDefault();


            context.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, data);

            if (data.dataId != oldId) { return false; }

            data.dataId = newId;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I have some logging in there as well with timestamps cuz I keep track of the oldId.  I've seen (more than once) 6 seconds later the method called again using the wrong (old oldId) and the row is returned with the old oldId instead of the previously set newId.  This is impossible because dataId was changed to the newId and saved.  The newId never, ever matches the oldId and I've verified that this isn't happening.  The problem is happening randomly.  99% of the time it's fine, but when it returns the old data it creates a lot of bad data that I have to manually fix.

Should I be doing something after context.SaveChanges()? or am I using StoreWins incorrectly?

More info:

id:
Primary key/identity column.

newId:
This is the user Id of the person updating the row

oldId:
This is the user id of the person who last updated the row

I need to make sure the row wasn't changed by someone else before updating it.  Originally I had oldId in the LINQ code but changed it while trying to figure out why old data was coming back.

The point is if someone else changes the row and it's already been changed by someone else I need to notify the user.

Today I saw 16 seconds later old data was returned by the LINQ code (I have timestamps).  I'm beginning to think the problem is that the changes aren't actually being saved sometimes or it's some kind of caching issue.

Update:
I think I might know why.. running some tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen it done in the manner you are doing it. Usually you attempt a save in a try block. if it fails because of a concurrency exception then you do the context.refresh in your catch block;

```
    try
    {
        int num = context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
        context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, data);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: I have global error trapping.  Not around every single call.  It's not the problem.  It's not erroring.

Answer (score 0):

This line confuses me:

```
where d.id == id
```

Should it be

```
 where d.dataId == id
```

If not please explain what the difference between

`id`, `newId`, `oldId`, `data.id`, and `data.dataId`

Comment: No, it's looking up the row by the identity column.  I could (and did before) have it also include the oldId in the LINQ check but changed it while trying to figure out why old data was coming back.  The point is, 16 (just seen it today) seconds later old/wrong data is being returned.

Comment: Still makes no sense to me -- could you post the table design for my_table that might help.

Comment: This is just an example of a bigger table.  I'll update my description with more info.  I'm beginning to wonder if the problem is LINQ isn't saving the changes.  16 seconds later is a long time for data to come back old.